# scipy.minimize - "TypeError: numpy.float64' object is not callable running"

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors, scipy, minimize

Running the scipy.minimize function "I get TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable". Specifically during the execution of:

```
    .../scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
```

I already looked at previous similar topics here and usually this problem occurs due to the fact that as first input parameter of .minimize is not a 
function. I have difficulties in figure it out, because "a" is function.
What do you think?

```
    ### "data" is a pandas data frame of float values
    ### "w" is a numpy float array i.e. [0.11365704 0.00886848 0.65302202 0.05680696 0.1676455 ]

    def a(data, w):
        ### Return a negative float value from position [2] of an numpy array of float values calculated via the "b" function i.e -0.3632965490830499 
        return -b(data, w)[2]

    constraint = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})

    ### i.e ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
    bound = tuple((0, 1) for x in range (len(symbols)))

    opts = scipy.minimize(a(data, w), len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint)
```

Comment: Basically, the problem is that `a(data, w)` is a function call, not a function. Just `a` by itself is a function, ie without the parenthesis `(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

It should instead be:

```
opts = scipy.minimize(a, len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], args=(w,), method='SLSQP', bounds=bound, constraints=constraint)
```

## Details

`a(data, w)` is not a function, it's a function call. In other words `a(data, w)`  effectively has the value and type of the return value of the function `a`. `minimize` needs the actual function without the call (ie without the parentheses `(...)` and everything in-between), as its first parameter.

From the [`scipy.optimize.minimize` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy-optimize-minimize):

> scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
>
> ...
>
> fun : callable
>
> The objective function to be minimized. Must be in the form f(x, *args). The optimizing argument, x, is a 1-D array of points, and args is a tuple of any additional fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function.
>
> ...
>
> args : tuple, optional
>
> Extra arguments passed to the objective function...

So, assuming `w` is fixed (at least with respect to your desired minimization), you would pass it to `minimize` via the `args` parameter, as I've done above.

Comment: `line 99 opts = opt.minimize(a, args = (data, w), len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint) ^ SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument ` This is the output.

Comment: @Nipper It looks like you're using Raubtaube's answer, which has invalid syntax (which is why you're getting the error message). Try the one I posted.

Comment: Sorry I did not read carefully. Just done as you suggested and the result is `line 99 opts = opt.minimize(a, len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], args = (, weights), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I need to swap the position of w in args because the b function first input is data which is a data frame (b function can not perform operation such as .shift() on w which is a numpy.array).

Comment: @Nipper You don't need to swap the position of `w`, `minimize` will do that for you. `args = (, weights)` is also not valid Python syntax. `len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),]` is your initial guess for `data`. `minimize` does not need anything else. It knows that the first entry in `args` is supposed to be the second argument passed to `a`

Comment: `opts = opt.minimize(a, len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], args = (w, ), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint)   ERROR line 16, in b 
    r1d = np.log(data / data.shift(1))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'shift'`

Comment: @Nipper your error message changed. That's good! It means you're making progress. It looks like you solved your original "not callable" problem. The issue now is that `minimize` will always pass `data` in as a `numpy` array, not as a pandas dataframe. You'll need to add a line to the start of `a` that will perform the array to dataframe conversion when it's needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168747/discussion-between-nipper-and-tel).

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the function, but the evaluated result to minimize.

```
opts = scipy.minimize(a,  len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint, args = (data,w))
```

Should work.

Edit: Fixed stupid syntax error.

Comment: `line 99
    opts = opt.minimize(a, args = (data, w), len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),], method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bound, constraints = constraint)
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument `   This is the output.

Comment: The syntax isn't valid. You need to swap `args = (data,w)` and `len(symbols) * [1. / len(symbols),]`. Also, it should be `args=(w,)`. `minimize` needs to be able to freely manipulate the first argument to `a`