# TypeError with scipy.optimize when minimizing Cost func

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, minimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to optimize 9 variables in W((1×9)matrix) by using scipy.optimize.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func(W):
    W = W.reshape(1,9) #(1,9)
    Y = df0.values.reshape(49,1) #(49,1)
    X = df1.values.reshape(49,1) #(49,9)
    Z = np.dot(X, W.T) #(49, 1)
    Z = np.abs(Z - Y) #(49, 1)
    Cost = np.sum(Z ,axis=0, keepdims=True)
    return Cost[0][0]  #float

W = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': W[1]-W[0]})

result = minimize(func, x0=W0, constraints=cons, method="SLSQP")
```

But I get a TypeError like this

```
'numpy.int32' object is not callable
```

I changed the 'cons' to

```
def cons(W):
    return W

cons = (
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons}
)
```

Then it worked fine and I got a result

```
     fun: 125.4977648197736
     jac: array([26.3666687 , 39.73333454, 46.56666756, 32.76666737, 38.23333454,
       25.20000076,  9.        ,  5.        ,  5.76666737])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 332
     nit: 24
    njev: 24
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([7.36486798e-03, 8.29918593e-03, 9.61602518e-02, 9.17950729e-03,
       2.98795999e-12, 3.73831662e-12, 3.59100171e-12, 4.73656828e-01,
       1.77345002e+00])
```

I can't reach out to a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact, that scipy's minimize needs an actual function (not output of it) to minimize properly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776015/scipy-minimize-typeerror-numpy-float64-object-is-not-callable-running). Your above code works, because you pass function  reference to the callable one (cons, not cons(W)). You can try creating a lambda function for it, for example:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda *args: W[1]-W[0]})
```